# how to sepratly on admin folder in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Friends i am php developer i did customize the url in example is

From : http://example.net/page.php?post_id=contact/

To : http://example.net/contact/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
#RewriteBase use only home/phtml/www/ this kind of path
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-/]+)$ page.php?post_id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-/]+)/$ page.php?post_id=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

its working fine on above that htaccess code but it have some problem. What is i got "admin" folder for control panel purpose. In which how to redirect to http://example.net/admin/ correctly any option this in htaccess?

My error is: http://example.net/page.php?post_id=admin/

How to Solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip all directories from your rewrite rule. Use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z/-]+)/?$ page.php?post_id=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

- Also you should keep unescaped hyphen at first or last place in a *character class*.
- I combined 2 of your rules into one using optional trailing slash.

Comment: I need more than one url customize example RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z/-]+)/?$ admin/index.php?post_id=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by **more than one url customize example RewriteRule**?

Comment: if i need another php file customize example: 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z/-]+)/?$ category.php?post_id=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: That won't work because it is same pattern as first rule. You can have a different path like `RewriteRule ^cat/([a-zA-Z/-]+)/?$ category.php?post_id=$1 [L,QSA] `

Comment: this is not working `^cat/([a-zA-Z/-]+)/?$ category.php?post_id=$1 [L,QSA]` in our htaccess

Comment: This is old question to answer a different problem. It would be better if you open a new question so that I can address new problem separately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732210/htaccess-not-working-in-seprate-folder